# Find the expected value of $Y$

Tags: probability, simulation

A coding challenge was given to me. The problem reads:

> Given the value of $N$,
> $$x=\text{rand}()\text{ mod } N$$
> $$Y=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}}$$
> find the expected value of $Y$. Note that $\text{rand}$  returns an integer between  $0$ and $10^{100}$  (inclusive) uniformly at random.

I argued as follows. The existence of the limit may be proved via induction.

Clearly $N$ cannot be negative and if it is $1$ then $x=0\implies \mathbb{E}[Y]=0$. Then let us assume $N>0$ and noting that

$$Y=\sqrt{x+Y}\implies Y^2-Y-x=0\implies Y=\frac12(1+\sqrt{1+4x})$$

we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\frac12(1+\sqrt{1+4x})\right]=\frac12+\frac12\mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{1+4x}\right]=\frac12\left(1+\mathbb{E}\left[\sqrt{1+4x}\right]\right).$$

The latter may be approximated making use of the strong law of large numbers.

A rudimental python code I wrote is

```
import random, math

random.seed(a=123)

def simulate(n, sims):

    sum_RVs = 0
    simulations = sims

    if n == 1:
        return 0

    elif n <= 0:
        return 'Error'

    for _ in range(simulations):
            #one can approximate with random.randint(0,n-1) if n not too large
        x = random.randint(0, 10**100)%n
        sum_RVs += math.sqrt(1+4*x)
    
    expected_Y = 0.5*(1+sum_RVs/simulations)

    return expected_Y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    for i in range(0,6):
        sims = 10**(i+1)
        exp_Y = simulate(10, sims)
        if exp_Y == 'Error':
            print('Invalid N.')
            break
        else:
            print('Simulations: 10^'+str(i+1)+' '*2+'E[Y]','{:f}'.format(exp_Y))
```

which, with $N = 10$ and $\text{n. simulations} = 10^6$, yields $2.538248$. From the plot below we can note convergence

[image: simulation with N = 10]

However, the answer given for equal $N$ is $2.43798953$. My answer also differs from the given answer ($=1.6964725$) when $N=5$. If I run the above program with $1$ million simulations, I obtain $\mathbb{E}[Y]\approx1.896765$ (even if I use $10$ simulations I obtain a value greater than $1.8$).

Using *Mathematica* with $N = 10$

```
N[Expectation[0.5 (1 + Sqrt[1 + 4 (Mod[x, 10])]),Distributed[x,DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 10^(100)}]]]]
```

yields $2.53799$.

However, substituting my derivation with the initial definition (truncated)

```
N[Expectation[Sqrt[Nest[Mod[x, 10] + Sqrt[#] &, 1, 10]], 
  Distributed[x, DiscreteUniformDistribution[{0, 10^(100)}]]]]
```

yields again $2.53799$. I am not sure how the $2.43798953$ answer was obtained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your computation of the limit $Y$ is valid only for $x\neq 0$. For $x=0$ you get $y=1$ but actually $y=0$. The polynomial for $x=0$ is $Y^2-Y=0$, which has two roots, $Y=1$ and $Y=0$, and the correct root is $Y=0$.

This means your answer is  too high by $1/N$, which matches what you are seeing: an  error of 0.1 for $N=10$ and 0.2 for $N=5$

(I found this by comparing to the actual iterated limit, which converges quite fast; a few iterations is enough)

Comment: Any ideas why Mathematica gives $2.53$ using the nested radicals?

Comment: Nope. No idea. But I don't speak Mathematica

Comment: Maybe  you could drop the `Expectation` and get a sequence of possible values of $y$, and see what the smallest one was?

Comment: Oh, I see. It's just a branch problem. You want the negative square root and Mathematica's `Sqrt` is the positive square root